# How to stop scrapy spider but process all wanted items?

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I have in my pipleline a method to check if the post date of the item is older then that found in mysql, so let `lastseen` be the newest datetime retrieved from database:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if item['post_date'] < lastseen:
        # set flag to close_spider
        # raise DropItem("old item")
```

This code basically works except: I check the site on hourly basis just to get the new posts, if I don't stop the spider it will keep crawling on thousands of pages, if I stop the spider on flag, chances are few requests will not be processed, since they may came back in queue after spider closed, even though those might be newer in post date, having said that, is there a workaround for a more precise scraping?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your setup, but you can fetch `lastseen` from MySQL when initializing your spider and stop generating Requests in your callbacks when the response contains the item with `postdate < lastseen`, hence basically moving the logic to stop crawling directly inside the Spider instead of the pipeline.

It can sometimes be simpler to pass an argument to your spider

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a lastseen=20130715
```

and set property of your Spider to test in your callback (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, lastseen=None):
        self.lastseen = lastseen
        # ...


    def parse_new_items(self, reponse):

        follow_next_page = True

        # item fetch logic
        for element in <some_selector>:

            # get post_date
            post_date = <extract post_date from element>

            # check post_date
            if post_date < self.lastseen:
                follow_next_page = False
                continue

            item = MyItem()
            # populate item...
            yield item

        # find next page to crawl
        if follow_next_page:

            next_page_url = ...

            yield Request(url = next_page_url, callback=parse_new_items)
```

Comment: it turns out scrapy by default uses LIFO queue, to force it crawl in BFO order, i need to have `DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.FifoMemoryQueue'` in my settings, adding the fact that urls in request queue follows some order, then this indeed solves my problem, although i am not sure about the efficiency part. thanks

Comment: Indeed, it gently assumes you process next pages one page at a time, following one "next" link of some sort.
If you queue a lot of requests, for example for all pages in a pagination footer, you may end up parsing pages that are much older than your last_seen. I dont think it's less efficient than the pipeline filter, it prevents items being queue in the pipeline at least. What do others think?